# Regex for property paths

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match property-syntax with a Javascript regex. Is there a reliable way to do this? I would need to match a string like the following-

```
someobject.somekey.somechildkey.somegrandchildkey
```

I don't need the path members, I just need to know if a string contains a path. For example, given a string like this

```
This is some long string that contains a property.path.syntax, and I need to test it.
```

Comment: You'll need to put more scope on this. What kinds of paths do you need to support? Suppose I have `someobject['somekey']["some" + "child" + " key"][foo]` (where `foo` is a variable containing `"somegrandchildkey"`), do you need to support that? What about other expressions (`someobject[foo ? 'somekey' : "someotherkey"]`)?

Comment: Also note that the valid list of JavaScript identifier characters is **large**. It's not like some languages that only allow `[a-zA-Z_]`. And there are basically no limits on property names (e.g., if you exprss them as strings), only property name literals. More: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6

Comment: For this application the paths are limited to period separated path syntax. No obj[path][childpath]. Also, we can safely assume in this implementation, that the "keys" will not be anything not human readable, so [a-zA-Z] should be valid

Comment: @ thebringking: There's lots of readable characters outside the a-zA-Z range, such as `ç`, `ö`, `ñ`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var expr = /[a-zA-Z_]([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)+/i;
expr.test("your.test.case");
```

The above regexp:

- doesn't match `.test`
- doesn't match `test.`
- doesn't match `test`
- doesn't match `0test`, because it cannot be a Javascript property (you cannot start the name of a variable with a number)

**EDIT**: as suggested by [Paulchenkiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1558455/paulchenkiller), and also considering the `i` at the end stands by "case insensitive", you can also use the following shorter form:

```
var expr = /[a-z_](\w*\.[a-z_]\w*)+/i;
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/\b(?:\S+?\.)+\S+\b/g
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wV4iZ1)

---

This is bounded by two word boundaries, which should work in most cases (a word character next to a non-word character).  Then we lazily repeat 1+ non-whitespace character followed by a `.` (which needs to be escaped).  We use `\S` for non-whitespace, because like @TJCrowder said, properties can [contain many characters](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6).  There always has to be another set of non-whitespace characters after the last period.

Answer (score 0):

Working within the limits you've identified in the comments:

```
/(?:[a-zA-Z_$]+[\w$]*)(?:\.[a-zA-Z_$]+[\w$]*)+/g
```

[Live Copy with details](http://regex101.com/r/fW6sT0) (The `g` flag if you need to do this repeated.)

That says:

- Anything starting with `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_`, or `$` *(emphasizing **again** this is an incomplete list)*
- ...followed by any number of those plus digits
- Followed by one or more non-capturing groups of the same thing, but starting with a `.`

Or if you need it *not* to match `one.that` and `should.not` in:

```
blah one.that.1should.not blah
```

Then:

```
/(?:\s|^)((?:[a-zA-Z_$]+[\w$]*)(?:\.[a-zA-Z_$]+[\w$]*)+)(?:\s|$)/g
```

[Live Copy](http://regex101.com/r/bD8fI3)

That says the same thing as the one earlier, but plus:

- Tequires whitespace or beginning-of-input to start with (`(?:\s|^)`) and whitespace-or-end-of-input at the end (`(?:\s|$)`).
- Uses a capture group so you can get just the property path without the optional whitespace on either side of it

Just to recap, the valid list of JavaScript identifier characters is *very large*, much larger than `\w` (which is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). It's not like some languages that only allow those characters. All *sorts* of normal-to-large-numbers-of-people characters are allowed, such as ç, ö, ñ (and arabic, and Japanese, and Chinese, and ...). And there are basically no limits on property names (e.g., if you exprss them as strings), only property name literals. More: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6

Comment: This also captures plain words in the string separated by spaces

Comment: @t-j-crowder, yes sorry I wasn't explicit, I assumed the example was clear enough.

Comment: @thebringking: I've fixed the answer. (And yes, the example was clear enough, sorry. I'm on meds for a back spasm, running at ~45%. :-) )

Comment: @thebringking: Question: Should `blah one.that.1should.not blah` result in two matches (`one.that` and `should.not`), or none?